# Is the Schwarzian Derivative a connection?

Tags: differential-geometry, dynamical-systems, projective-geometry, mobius-transformation, sturm-liouville

The Schwarzian derivative is the quadratic differential

$$ S(f) = \Bigg( \frac{f'''}{f'} - \frac{3}{2} \Big( \frac{f''}{f'} \Big)^2 \Bigg) (dz)^2 .$$

Bill Thurston, in his Math overflow answer [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/38105/is-there-an-underlying-explanation-for-the-magical-powers-of-the-schwarzian-deri) and his paper "Zippers and Univalent Functions" presents one interpretation of the Schwarzian derivative as being the "rate of change of the best approximating Mobius transformation of $f$."

More rigorously, define
$$ M(f, w)(z)$$
to be the Mobius transformation
$$
M(f, w)(z) = \frac{az + b}{cz + d}
$$
that has the same value, first derivative, and second derivative of $f(z)$ at $z = w$. There are four unknowns, $a,b,c,d$ and the four equations
$$
ad - bc = 1
$$
$$
M(f,w)(w) = f(w)
$$
$$
(\partial_z  M(f,w) )(w) = f'(w)
$$
$$
(\partial_z^2  M(f,w) )(w) = f''(w)
$$
which allows us to solve for $a,b,c,d$ explicitly (but the expressions are not enlightening so I will not write them here).

Thurston's "rate of change" of the best approximating Mobius transformation is defined to be

$$
\frac{d}{dt} M(f, w)^{-1} \circ M(f, w + t) \Big\rvert_{t = 0}.
$$
Note that because, for any Mobius transformation $A$,
$$
M(A \circ f, w) = A \circ M(f, w).
$$
This implies that if we send $f \mapsto A \circ f$, our rate of change becomes
$$
\frac{d}{dt} M(A \circ f, w)^{-1} \circ M(A \circ f, w + t) \Big\rvert_{t = 0} $$
$$=
\frac{d}{dt} M(f, w)^{-1} \circ A^{-1} \circ A\circ M(f, w + t) \Big\rvert_{t = 0}.
$$
and the overall expression doesn't change.

In fact, it can be explicitly shown that this is actually just the Schwarzian derivative:

$$
\frac{d}{dt} M(f, w)^{-1} \circ M(f, w + t) \Big\rvert_{t = 0} = \frac{1}{2} (z - w)^2 \Bigg( \frac{f'''}{f'} - \frac{3}{2} \Big( \frac{f''}{f'} \Big)^2 \Bigg).
$$

Here is my question: the schematic expression $\partial_t M^{-1} M(t)$ looks an awful lot to me like the expression for a connection. Can the Schwarzian derivative be thought of, in any way, as a connection? What is the base space and the Principal bundle? Also, connections are usually thought of as "Lie algebra valued one forms," but the Schwarzian has a $(dz)^2$ instead of a $dz$. What is the relevance of that?

Answer (score 2):

The Schwarzian derivative shows up in the setting of projective structures on $\mathbf{R}$. Let $f:\mathbf{R}\rightarrow\mathbf{R}$ and think of the value of $f$ as an affine coordinate on $\mathbf{RP}^1$ so that $f$ is a curve in $\mathbf{RP}^1$. This curve can be lifted to a areavelocity("angular momentum")-preserving curve $\phi(t)$ in $\mathbf{R}^2$ (homogenous coordinates on $\mathbf{RP}^1$) which satisfies the Sturm-Liouville-equation
$$
\phi''+u(t)\phi=0
$$
where
$$
u(t)=\frac{1}{2}S(f)
$$
with Schwarzian derivative
$$
S(f)=\frac{f'''}{f'}-\frac{3}{2}\left(\frac{f''}{f'}\right)^2
$$
A projective structure is equivalent to a projective connection so this can also be stated as bundle over the base $\mathbf{R}$ with fiber $\mathbf{RP}^1$ and an $\mathrm{sl}(2)$-valued connection one-form. A projective connection has an associated developing map onto $\mathbf{RP}^1$ and this map is the given $f:\mathbf{R}\rightarrow\mathbf{RP}^1$.